# How to adapt border-radius on different screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply **border-radius** effect on a particular div. The code I used is this:

```
/* Multiple compatibility with border radius */
/* CSS 3 */
border-radius: 50%;
/* Firefox versiones 3.x */
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
/* Safari desde 3.2 hasta la 4 */
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
/* Khtml Conqueror */
-khtml-border-radius: 50%;
```

And with that, I simulate a circle :D! Since there, everythig is ok. I wrote some lines so it fits for different resolutions, but today I discovered something when I used my father's computer.

I use a 22 inch screen full HD. My father has a 17 inch screen. I tried my design on different resolutions on my 22 inch screen, and they were correct. But when I went to my 17 inch father's monitor and I opened my site, my circles looked like an egg! I was guessing how could it be! I ensured my design with my 22 inches monitor, and with all of them, from 800 x 600 from 1920 x 1080, the design looked correctly.

Of course, I immediately thought it should be the monitor's width. As I work with % for positioning my Web page, it makes the circles to look as eggs. But I'm not sure if changing this % would solve this problem and produce anothers one because I change that.

So, how can I make my circles look like circles in different screen inches??

Thank you!

EDIT:

Ok, I edit the post as it doesn't clarify everything. My father's resolution: 1024 x 768. I tried it on my 22 inches screen and it looks perfectly. But when I go to the 17 inches screen, they are eggs again!  >_<

And here I paste the screenshot of the eggs:

[image: The eggs!]
Sorry, with toolbars and so...

I ensure they look as circles on a 22 inches screen...

**EDIT**

I changed both properties to 16%. Now it looks like this:

[image: New eggs!]

And now... I'm a bit lost. I think I might take a look to my code again...

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of the "eggs" on your father's screen (including toolbars if you can). This is actually an interesting question.

Comment: what was your father's screen resolution? I suspect the screen itself is skewed / stretched or the screen is not running a native resolution. another thing to check is to look at a screenshot / image of a circle that appears as a circle on your computer.. and if that appears as an egg on your dad's screen.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly... but have you tried giving the divs their own id's, then applying the css to each of them separately? `div#dividname { border-radius: 50%; }`

Comment: @Moin Zaman - yeah I'm suspecting that too.

Comment: @poepje http://jsfiddle.net/7AN3R/ He has this.

Comment: @easwee I'm not sure what to do with that page?

Comment: @poepje - that is a sample of his problem - you said you didn't understand and also can't see how different ID's could fix this.

Comment: I see a circle (round div?) and some code, but still don't see how that's gonna make it any more clear. And I suggested that he *should* use different div id's.

Comment: Could it be because I use % for the width and height properties instead of px?
.circle
{ 
 width:8%; 
 height:16%;   
 position:absolute; 
 float:left; 
 text-decoration:none; 
 
 /* Multiple compatibility with border radius */
 /* CSS 3 */
 border-radius: 50%;
 /* Firefox versiones 3.x */
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 /* Safari desde 3.2 hasta la 4 */
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 /* Khtml Conqueror */
 -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
}

Comment: @Sonhja - Are you 100% sure that it is 1024 x 768 - the screenshot is 1280x1024 - that would distort your image indeed.

Comment: Yes, this one is 1280 x 1024, but the problem persists on both resolutions on a 17 inches monitor... (I was trying different resolutions when I made the screenshot...).

Comment: Do you think it could be the way I use the width and height properties for the circles? I use % instead of px... (See my comment above...)

Comment: @Sonhja - Well if you use 8% width and 16% height it is not ok. Try use same value for both measurements.

Comment: @Sonhja - I can probably see now what you are doing. A circle in math does not have a width and height since you measure his radius. You need to keep the percentage of the width and height the same ratio 1:1.

Comment: @easwee - Ok, give me some minutes as I'm away and I need to install my tools to try it. Let me try that... with so sense!

Comment: please use [the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) for extended discussions.

Comment: @easwee - Well, actually I could solve it by using px properties instead of %. For the moment is a step, but I need to dig deeper... Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

I grabbed your [website address from the image](http://smolinaperez.co.cc/).

You have the width and height of your boxes set as a percentage - this is a percentage of the containing element's width and height, so you can recreate this issue just by resizing your browser into different aspect ratios.

If the width is 16%, and you change the width of the browser, the circle will get wider but the height will be unchanged (you haven't made the browser any higher).

For example

Height: 100px and Width: 100px

- 16% of 100px is 16px wide
- 8% of 100px is 8px wide

Squash the browser to 100px high and 50px wide and you'll get circles:

- 16% of 50px is 8px wide
- 8% of 100px is 8px high

**Previous Answer**

It could be that the screen resolution is wrong, which is causing the screen itself to be stretched.

You can test this by viewing an image of a circle on the screen. If it is not round, the problem is in the computer settings not in your CSS.

If the circle displays correctly are you able to point us to a demo of the page or supply a bit more of your HTML and CSS so we can test it out? Another cause of this would be that the size of your boxes is not "square" before you add the border-radius.

[image: Circle]

[Circle courtesy of Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/CIRCLE_1.svg/220px-CIRCLE_1.svg.png).

Comment: It is not, on my machine the circles resize with changes to their containers size, just go to his site an you can see.

Comment: This is totally the answer. The circles stretch and distort along with the aspect ratio of the browser window.  It has nothing to do with monitor size.

Comment: @Sparky672 - Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @Sohnee - I totally understand what you mean. I will check all what you say.

Comment: @Sohnee - Sohnee, I tried to put a fixed value with px, and it worked. I don't really like it and I will totally not use it. But I think what you say is the  deepest and most correct explanation for these, so I will study it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sonhja, I don't know what's to explain about my other comment?  Just grab the bottom right corner of your browser window and change its size.  Watch the circles distort and stretch as you make the window narrower, wider, shorter or longer.

Comment: @Sparky672 - Yes, now I realized... I don't know how I didn't see it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your comments what is happening to you atm is this: http://jsfiddle.net/7AN3R/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">

.mydiv {
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:8%;
    height:16%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:800px;height:600px;">
    <div class="mydiv">


    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try to use the same percentage for both width and height of your circle div.

Like

```
.circle{
border:1px solid #000;
width:8%;
height:8%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-khtml-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: `-khtml` and `-moz` prefixes are not needed nowadays

Comment: @Vladimir Starkov - it really depends for which audience you are making the website. In our country alot of libraries still use old Mozilla browsers <4 version with blocked updates. And they want you to support that in case you work for them. But yeah - in a perfect world...

Comment: `-moz` is need only for firefox 1 and lower, `-khtml` seems for safari 1